# Ternary equivalence relations that are not equivalent to some binary equivalance

Tags: soft-question, relations, equivalence-relations

1.Is there such a thing as ternary equivalence that is not equivalent or cant not be expressed as binary equivalence?

2.If there is such a thing as expressed in 1, are there any practical uses for it? Is such a an equivalence relation is still transitive? (I know in case of binary equivalence, transitivity is required, but in ternary case is transitivity still a requirement, if yes what does a ternary equivalent relationship might look like )

I am not sure how to phrase this question properly, so if you can understand what is being asked please go ahead and modify this.

Comment: Are you looking for ternary partial  analogues of equivalence relations? Or just ternary relations of some interest?

Comment: Thank you @AndréNicolas, yes, either and both. at this stage I take either. Is there a theorem that expresses whether any n-ary relation can be decomposed into n-1 ary relations? or how ? Then I will chase that one instead of this question

Comment: Any binary operation $\ast : A \times A \to A$ on a set $A$ defines a ternary relation $R$ on $A$ by $$a \ast b = c \Leftrightarrow (a, b, c) \in R ,$$ and these are exactly the ternary relations that have the property that for all $a, b \in A$ there is exactly one $c \in A$ such that $(a, b, c) \in R$. Probably these cannot in general be decomposed into binary operations in any reasonable sense.

Comment: An interesting one is betweenness.  Binary relations cannot in general be decomposed into unaries, whatever decompose may mean.  After that there are coding tricks, if we have enough arithmetic available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best-known example is the [collinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collinearity) relation among three points $C(x,y,z)$, which is an equivalence relation in that it satisfies the axioms of...

- **Symmetry**: $C(x,y,z)$ is invariant under permutations of $x, y, z$
- **Reflexivity**: $C(x,y,y)$
- **Transitivity**: $C(a,x,y)\land C(a,y,z)\to C(a,x,z)$

And there doesn't seem to be a reasonable way to "decompose" $C$ in terms of binary relations.

Comment: I think you need to require $a \ne y$ in the definition of transitivity.